Why was this post on 'the big lie' deleted by the community bot?
About two years ago (28th June 2022), the question What is the origin of this Hitler quote regarding lying? was deleted (yes, I'm slow, I only just noticed it yesterday). The question itself had 14 upvotes and 1 downvotes (so 13 upvotes), and the answer 22 upvotes. The deletion was done about three and a half years after the question was posted.
According to the site guidelines in the post How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion? on the main meta site,

The system will automatically delete any post, regardless of score,
answers, or the site it's on, when its owner's account is destroyed
(only done for users with no useful contributions such as spammers).
(shown as "User [x] destroyed" in the question timeline)
(my highlighting)

With 13 upvotes on the question, surely it cannot be said that this post isn't a useful contribution? Further, as the answer shows, it allows a myth to be debunked. That said, there does seem to be some contradiction with the earlier statement regardless of score. Nonetheless, one wonders what the point is of spending time researching and writing an answer when it's just going to get deleted even when well-received by the community.
In the course of searching for reasons for this post's deletion, I came across this History Meta post: Upvoted answer deleted due to removed user. The situation seems similar except that in that case, the post had a net score of zero, so I can why (according to the guidelines) it was deleted (but it's still unfair on the person who answered). Also, the deletion did not happen several years after the post was made.
It seems to me that the question about the 'big lie' should not have been removed from the question list (especially so long after it was made, i.e. it has been viewed many times and has no negative comments) and thus should be undeleted.

Appreciate you posting this here! As you can hopefully see, my thinking on the matter required a bit longer form than could reasonably be squeezed in a flag response. Plus if I'm being unreasonable (I don't think so, but unreasonable people rarely think they are), or even flat out wrong, this gives everyone a chance to say so.

The post appears to have been removed 2 years ago because, as you correctly intuited, the account that posted it got destroyed, with the "spam or nonsense" reason.
This is also the reason site mods like to use to destroy accounts that habitually ban evade, particularly when the ban was for posting offensive content. The reason for this is that it not only deletes all the account's content (including any nasty comments we might have missed), but it also makes it a bit more difficult for that person/spammer to create a new sock account.
As for this specific instance, it happens that it wasn't done by a site mod here, but rather by a SE network employee with mod privs. However, if you're curious why they did it, they explained in the destruction comments quite thoroughly. I think (and hope!) I wouldn't be doing something out of line to repeat that here:

Detail: User is being destroyed for repeat violations of the CoC &
ToS, posting content related to neo-nazi propaganda.

I can also see in there that the user got suspended network-wide out of another site before the mod came in here and cleaned up their crud. It seems pretty clear this was a specific well-known Nazi sockmaster that is still smearing their "content" on this site periodically today.
These days it probably wouldn't happen that way. What happens instead is that its a race. If we site mods find his dirty content first, we destroy the account. If SE network mods find it first, they'll instead merge the account with the master account (in this case I think suspended until the US Tricentennial), and then they painstakingly remove the new content. I've been told they kind of like it when we win.
In fact, we've got good enough at identifying this particular sock, that its highly unlikely any post of theirs is positively voted and has a whole answer. Even if it somehow (like in this case?) happened to end up "good" enough to merit it.

Next question: Should this be the way we do things going forward, just blindly deleting all ban-evading sock-puppet content?
Well, this is in fact how we moderate now. If anyone seriously wants that readdressed I'd like to see a different meta question specifically about that. I don't think that's what you're asking though. (I hope not)

Next question (that I think you do want answered here): In this one instance (and perhaps any future instances with positive voted posts) can we get this question and its answer back?
First off, if that's what this site wants (perhaps best judged by good argument answers here getting highly upvoted), then it probably ought to be done. However, I'm going to argue against it.
Personally, I'd say as a matter of policy, I think its a bad idea to ever revive destroyed sockpuppet content. Particularly from recurrent sockpuppets. Triply particularly from Nazi sockpuppets. This particular user posts their Nazi-adjacent questions not because they are curious, but because they want to promote the Nazi content in them. If you don't want to run a Nazi bar, you kick Nazis out even when they are being nice.
Nazis aside, I think its bad way to deal with a troll psychologically. They get their enjoyment from seeing their stuff on our site, making us waste our time, and getting people upset. This particular one is hounding us mercilessly, wasting tons of moderator time (both user and diamond) that could be better used elsewhere. I don't think we should even contemplate doing something that would reward that behavior.
Thirdly, there's a small practical matter: Questions with destroyed accounts are effectively dead questions. There's no possible way an answer can get a checkmark.
For all these reasons, if we'd really like to see that question, I'd much much prefer that someone (reasonable) re-asks it. Rephrased of course, both because we aren't thieves here, and because even if we were we wouldn't steal thoughts from Nazis. Even thieves have principles.

The post itself is pretty short, but for starters I think taking "Hitler" out of it would be a good change to it. A few links in the question showing there is indeed confusion on the matter would probably be appreciated too.

Thank for the time and effort you have put into this answer. I suspected that the user  destroyed was a nazi troll even though this question was worth asking (judging by the upvotes it got). However, in doing so, the SE employee seems to have thrown the baby out with bathwater. There ought to be an alternative which protects innocent users rather than sweeping their hard work out with the trash. Also, there is some confusion as to whether the SE employee actually followed the guidelines (as I pointed out in the question, there seems to be a contradiction in the part I quoted).

From your post, I discern three possibilities for bring this question 'back to life'. 1. Undelete, 2. Edit as per your suggestions and then undelete or, 3. Leave the original as deleted and instead re-post the question (with improvements).  You are (understandably) against option 1, but I'd be interested to know whether you think option 2 or option 3 is better.

@LarsBosteen - Definitely 3. I think we can probably merge the questions after that to save the highly-voted answer. If we want that question,  it should IMHO be written and posted by somebody who actually GAS about this site, and can accept answers.

I'm thinking of posting the question (with improvements and new links) and self-answering.
